# How to figure out browser scrolling issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, sharepoint, web-parts

I am developing a web part within Sharepoint that makes heavy use of 3rd party web services.

In my page, I have a view element (div#act1_show) that is collapsed. When I click on the expand button, the data is shown. No problem there.

The data of that element can be edited when that element is collapsed when I click the edit button. This actually hides the view element (div#act1_show) and shows a different edit element (div#act1_edit). No problem there.

However, when I first expand the view element (div#act1_show) and then click the edit button to open the edit element (div#act1_edit), the edit element is opened but now I can now longer scroll the page. That is, I can no longer use the scroll bar on the right of the browser window.

I've looked for any css position fixed but found none.

So, can anybody suggest how I go about figuring out how to find the cause of no longer being able to scroll with the browser's scroll bar?

Thanks

Comment: maybe some jsfiddle example ? then we could help you. Cheers

Comment: those elements are absolutely positioned? with different `z-index`s?

Comment: After very long debugging, I found that the "#" at the end of the url was causing that problem. Once that was removed, scrolling worked normally again. Thanks!